# par('usr') equivalent command for grid?

Tags: r, r-grid

When grid package is used to plot a figure, I want to find out something similar to `par('usr')` as in base R graphics. What command can do it?

https://r-graph-gallery.com/100-high-density-scatterplot-with-binning.html

For example, how to get the value equivalent to `par('usr')` in the following figure?

```
library(hexbin)
library(RColorBrewer)
 
# Create data
x <- rnorm(mean=1.5, 5000)
y <- rnorm(mean=1.6, 5000)
 
# Make the plot
bin<-hexbin(x, y, xbins=40)
my_colors=colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(11,'Spectral')))
plot(bin, main="" , colramp=my_colors , legend=F ) # the plot is based on grid if I understand it correctly.
```

Answer (score 0):

Viewports in grid have information similar to what `par()` shows in base graphics, though with different names.

`hexbin` sets up viewports for the plot and the legend that it displays.  To set the plot viewport as current, save the `hexbin` plot to a variable `p`, then use

```
pushHexport(p$plot.vp)
```

Now `current.viewport()` will return the grid viewport.  `str(current.viewport())` will show you what's stored in it.  In particular, `xscale` and `yscale` contain the limits of those two axes, similar to `par("usr")[1:2]` and `par("usr")[3:4]`.

The `hexbin` package gives access to some of these things directly in the `p$plot.vp` object:  see `class?hexVP` for details.  In particular, `p$plot.vp@xscale` gets the `xscale` property of the viewport.